# unique on filtered range with values returns 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On sheet 2, I have an filtered array and I'm trying to apply a unique formula to one of the columns with 10 rows, and the result is 0.  Can someone please help and explain?

Formula used to pull data into sheet 2

```
=sort(filter('sheet1'!A2:A12, 'sheet1'!A2:A12<>""),1,1)
```

And here is my result on sheet 2:

[image]

And then when I apply the unique formula to the list of IDs, it returns 0.  Can someone please explain and help?

To return the unique ids listed

Comment: Can we see the formula with UNIQUE?

Comment: =unique(A2:A13)

Comment: Did you try `=UNIQUE(A2#)` where `A2` is the cell in which the formula is located.

Comment: There has to be something else going on, because we cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: I just tried that and got the same result - no luck

Comment: As stated, we do not have enough information.  We cannot replicate from the information you have given.

Comment: What does *"to one of the columns with 10 rows"* mean? The screenshot is showing 12 rows, your formula uses 11 rows. Maybe you need to add the worksheet reference to Scott Craner's suggestion, e.g. `=UNIQUE(Sheet2!A2#)` i.e. you're not telling us where the formula is located.

Comment: or did you try: `=sort(UNIQUE(filter('sheet1'!A2:A12, 'sheet1'!A2:A12<>"")),1,1)`

Comment: Thanks all for the help - I couldn't get this to work, even as described with the worksheet reference, but did change the calculation option to manual in Formulas upon advice from another website, and it appears to work for now.

Comment: Ah, that means you were probably having a large file and it was showing `0` because the calculation wasn't done yet. If you would wait the spill would return.

Comment: Well noted - Thanks!